# Custom route for Swashbuckle

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

I am trying to register a custom route for swashbuckle.
However I can't figure this one out.

What I need to do is to add an extension to the current route.

So for example:
Instead of swagger/ui I need to set it to swagger.aspx/ui..
This is since my application will be hosted on a server where I have no access and its running IIS6.

Any ideas?

I have tried:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Remove(RouteTable.Routes["swagger_docs"]);
RouteTable.Routes.Remove(RouteTable.Routes["swagger_ui"]);
config.EnableSwagger("docs.aspx/{apiVersion}/swagger", c => c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "A title for your API")).EnableSwaggerUi("swagger.aspx/{*assetPath}");
```

But with no success... :(

Answer (score 0):

In theory that should work! there is even a similar config in the UnitTests:
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/e0053e1864defa3c4f73ca2a960eb876e257cc9e/Swashbuckle.Tests/Owin/MultiSwaggerOwinStartup.cs

But there could be a bug lurking in there...

Your best bet will be to create a custom swashbuckle that suit your needs.

You will need to change the DefaultRouteTemplate:
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/e0053e1864defa3c4f73ca2a960eb876e257cc9e/Swashbuckle.Core/Application/HttpConfigurationExtensions.cs#L15